# eBPF tools - skb_network_header crashes in a BPF Kernel trace function

Tags: ebpf, kprobe

I am looking to trace `ip_forward_finish`. The intent is to trace latency of all TCP connections going through a linux based gateway router.  Hence thought of tracing `ip_forward_finish` kernel function. And capture the time-stamp of `SYN`, `SYN-ACK` and `ACK` messages at the router.

The issue is accessing `iphdr` inside the trace function makes the verifier complain with the following error:

```
bpf: Failed to load program: Permission denied
0: (79) r6 = *(u64 *)(r1 +96)
1: (b7) r1 = 0
2: (6b) *(u16 *)(r10 -24) = r1
3: (bf) r3 = r6
4: (07) r3 += 192
5: (bf) r1 = r10
6: (07) r1 += -24
7: (b7) r2 = 2
8: (85) call bpf_probe_read#4
9: (69) r1 = *(u16 *)(r10 -24)
10: (55) if r1 != 0x8 goto pc+7
 R0=inv(id=0) R1=inv8 R6=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
11: (69) r1 = *(u16 *)(r6 +196)
R6 invalid mem access 'inv'

HINT: The invalid mem access 'inv' error can happen if you try to dereference
    memory without first using bpf_probe_read() to copy it to the BPF stack.
    Sometimes the bpf_probe_read is automatic by the bcc rewriter, other times
    you'll need to be explicit.
```

The code fragment I originally had was as below and the crash occurs when an access to `ip_Hdr->protocol` is made. And I also checked that `ip_Hdr` is not null.

```c
int trace_forward_finish(struct pt_regs *ctx,struct net *net,
                         struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (skb->protocol != htons(ETH_P_IP))
        return 0;

    struct iphdr* ip_Hdr = (struct iphdr *) skb_network_header(skb);

    if (ip_Hdr->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
        return 0;

    /// More code
}
```

Per the HINT in the message, I did try to change to `bpf_probe_read` but still the same outcome

```c
int trace_forward_finish(struct pt_regs *ctx,struct net *net,
                         struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (skb->protocol != htons(ETH_P_IP))
        return 0;

    struct iphdr ip_Hdr;
    bpf_probe_read(&ip_Hdr, sizeof(ip_Hdr), (void*)ip_hdr(skb)); 

    if (ip_Hdr.protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
        return 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

bcc will try to transform your dereferences of kernel pointers into calls to `bpf_probe_read`. You can see that happening by passing `debug=4` to the `BPF()` call.

In your case, I suspect that you would need to include function `skb_network_header` in your code so that bcc is able to rewrite it.

If that's not sufficient, then you might need a manual call to `bpf_probe_read` to retrieve structure `struct iphdr` from `skb_network_header`'s pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry - I am a bit new to this. How do I include skb_network_heade r to make bcc rewrite it. Can you point me to some examples? And I have tried manual call to bpf_probe_read as per the second code fragment but did not help. Is there something wrong in the way I am using it?

Comment: I would replace the call to `skb_network_header` with its source code (it's a single line). For `bpf_probe_read` did you check the transformations bcc does with `debug=4`?